# Understanding the scope of operators in C++

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, scope, argument-dependent-lookup

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Foo
{
    class Baz { };   

    std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& ostream , const Baz& baz )
    {
        return ostream << "operator<<\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo::Baz();
}
```

I define an `operator<<` in the `Foo` namespace. Why it can be called from the global scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**DRTL**

The compiler can find the user-defined `operator<<` through **argument-dependent lookup**.

**Explanation**

The call

```
 std::cout << Foo::Baz();
```

is actually an infix shorthand for

```
 operator<<(std::cout, Foo::Baz());
```

Because the function call is **unqualified** (i.e. without any namespace prefix or surrounding parentheses), the compiler will not only do **ordinary name lookup** (outwards from the local function scope), but also argument-dependent lookup (a.k.a **ADL**) for other overloads of function `operator<<` in all the **associated namespaces** of both arguments `std::cout` and class `Baz`. These associated namespaces are `std` and `Foo` in this case.

Thus argument-dependent lookup will find the definitions

```
 std::operator<<(std::ostream&, /* all the builtin types and Standard strings and streams */)
 Foo::operator<<(std::ostream&, const& Baz)
```

After name-lookup, **argument deduction** will fail for all the `std::operator<<` overloads. This is why **overload resolution** will find that the user-defined `Foo::operator<<` is in fact the only match. That's why it is called.

Comment: @Kolyunya Glad to have been of help!